# How do I dispose a scene in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I am working with multiple Scenes in my project, and I have found that using the `stage.setScene()` method will keep the previous scene running in the background. I want to dispose of the previous scene entirely (or prevent it from running/taking up memory/etc) when I switch scenes.

Comment: `stage.close()`

Comment: `stage.close()` closes the entire window, right? I am trying to switch scenes but keep the same window.

Comment: Ah yes, my bad. In terms of destroying the Scene object so it doesn't take up excess memory, I think your best bet is to dereference the Scene object and let garbage collection do the rest.

Comment: "_and I have found that using `stage.setScene()` method will keep previous scene running in the background_". How did you determine this? You should [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] demonstrating this behavior. If you have no references to the Scene then it should be garbage collected some time after being replaced by the new Scene. If it stays in memory permanently that sounds like a bug in JavaFX. Note, however, that the garbage collector won't necessarily run immediately.

Comment: @ShivashriganeshMahato I think that I attempted to dereference it at one point? I tried setting the first scene to `null` after switching scenes but it resulted in a bunch of weird errors and I couldn't figure out a way to get around those errors.

@Slaw I am using `TranslateTransition` on one of the nodes in the first scene to create an infinite scrolling background. When I switch to another scene, then back to that scene, the background will still have moved.

I will work on updating the question!

Comment: The fact that it's even possible to go back to the original scene means that you still keep a strong reference to the scene. Java cannot garbage collect such objects. (I'm not assuming you stored the reference using [`SoftReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ref/SoftReference.html)). `TranslateTransition` should also store a strong reference to the scene via it's `node` property; Not sure a animation will be garbage collected, but surely a running one will not be available to garbage collection, since it's still listening to pulses from the toolkit